# .findOne is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js

In my app, I tried to use `.findOne` but I take error. This is my error:-

```
TypeError: User.findOne is not a function
at Strategy._verify (/Users/AES/twitterm/config/passport.js:21:8)
at Strategy.authenticate (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/passport-local/lib/strategy.js:88:12)
at attempt (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:361:16)
at authenticate (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/passport/lib/middleware/authenticate.js:362:7)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at next (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:137:13)
at next (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:131:14)
at Route.dispatch (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/route.js:112:3)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at /Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:281:22
at Function.process_params (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:335:12)
at next (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:275:10)
at Function.handle (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:174:3)
at router (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:47:12)
at Layer.handle [as handle_request] (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/layer.js:95:5)
at trim_prefix (/Users/AES/twitterm/node_modules/express/lib/router/index.js:317:13)
```

And the code file in this link https://www.dropbox.com/s/gbjtc7ilm9wnzj2/passport.js?dl=0
I want selection for this error

Answer (score 1):

Just off the top of my head, it looks like you never imported Mongoose to be able to use the `findOne` method on the model.

Comment: How I can import it?

Answer (score 0):

[you have FindOne](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7Uyad.png)

Your code has it as FindOne. try changing it findOne

It also doesn't look like mongoose was imported.

```
npm i --save mongoose
```

and import it

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because you are not using the correct mongoose model or your mongoose model isn't used correctly.

Only a valid mongoose model has a `findOne` function